# Calculate Average with Arrays from User Input

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a program that will calculate an average of arrays up to 10 numbers. Here are the requirements:

The program uses methods to:
1.Get the numbers entered by the user
2.Calculate the average of the numbers entered by the user
3.Print the results

The first method should take no arguments and return an array of doubles that the user entered.

The second method should take an array of doubles (the return value of the first method above) as its only argument and return a double (the average).

The third method should take an array of doubles and a (single) double value as arguments but have no return value.

I tried the below, but the biggest problem I'm running into (that I can tell so far at least) is that the program is printing both statements before allowing the user input. I know how to do this normally, but I think I'm getting confused because of the array piece. Thanks much.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] userNumbers = printUserNums();
    double average = getAverage(userNumbers);
    printAverage(average, userNumbers);

}

public static double[] printUserNums() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter five to ten numbers separated by spaces: ");
    double[] userNums = new double[10];

    return userNums;
}

public static double getAverage(double[] userNums) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    double average = 0.0;
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < userNums.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + userNums[i];

    }
    if (counter != 0) {
        average = sum / userNums.length;
    }

    return average;

}

public static void printAverage(double average, double[] userNums) {
    System.out.printf("The average of the numbers " + userNums + " is %.2f", average);

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you creating and returning an empty array in `printUserNums()`? You aren’t even reading in user input.

Comment: Why do you need the first line in method: `getAverage()` ?

Comment: Your array in the method printUserNums() is never initialized. You need to assign the value from scanner to the array. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795350/how-to-put-a-scanner-input-into-an-array-for-example-a-couple-of-numbers

Comment: @KenWhite it’s actually not invalid syntax. It’ll just display the array’s hash code. For instance, `[D@1540e19d`.

Comment: Don't mix input with calculations.  Do yourself a favor and take that scanner code out of the getAverage method.

Answer (score 0):

You are never asking for the numbers!
You need to ask for an input from the scanner:

```
String inputValue = in.next();
```

and then split your full string (containing the numbers separated by space) using space as your regex to get the numbers:

```
String[] stringValues = inputValue.split("\\s+");
```

You should probably have some kind of checking to verify that there is at least 5 values and no more than 10 values by your requirements.
If the checking passes, just loop through your array and convert the string values to double values with Double.valueOf(String s) and store them in your double array.

It's not how I would normally get numbers from user input but if you want to have them in one go, this should work.