# Why does implemented insertion sort with arraylist give no output and no error?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I was hoping anyone could help me with the following code in Java, because even though it shows no error, it gives no array as output:
I am trying to implement insertion sort. I made 2 packages and classes; a main one and a InsertionSort one.
The code I used is:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import insertionSort.InsertionSort;

public class Main implements Cloneable{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<Integer> unsortedArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        unsortedArray.add(8);
        unsortedArray.add(7);
        unsortedArray.add(6);
        unsortedArray.add(5);
        unsortedArray.add(4);
        unsortedArray.add(0);
        unsortedArray.add(2);
        InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort(unsortedArray);

        System.out.println("Initial unsorted array: ");
        for(int i:InsertionSort.inputArray()){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        sort.doInsertionSort();

        System.out.println("Sorted array after performing insertion sort: ");
        for(int i:InsertionSort.inputArray()){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

    }
}


package insertionSort;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InsertionSort {

private static ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> inputArray() {
        return array;
    }   

    public InsertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> inputArray){
        InsertionSort.array = array;
    }

    public void doInsertionSort(){
        for (int j = 1; j<array.size(); j++){
            int key = array.get(j);
            int i;
            for (i=j-1; i>=0 && array.get(i)> key; i--){
                array.set(i+1,array.get(i));
                array.set(i+1, key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is just the text without the arrays. Hope someone can help! Keep in mind I am a novice. Thank you kindly in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assigns the `array` variable to itself :

```
public InsertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> inputArray){
    InsertionSort.array = array;
}
```

This should be :

```
public InsertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> inputArray){
    array = inputArray;
}
```

Besides you have a little mistake in your swap.

`array.set(i+1, key);` should be executed after the inner loop.
It sets the element of the outer loop (referenced by the `key` variable) at its correct position.
This has to be done only when you sorted the elements at its left, so after the inner loop.

So this :

```
for (i=j-1; i>=0 && array.get(i)> key; i--){
    array.set(i+1,array.get(i));
    array.set(i+1, key);
}
```

should be :

```
for (i=j-1; i>=0 && array.get(i)> key; i--){
    array.set(i+1,array.get(i));
}
array.set(i+1, key);
```

---

As a side note, you don't use correctly instance and static modifiers.

You create an instance of `InsertionSort` :

```
InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort(unsortedArray);
```

But the constructor values a static field.

```
...
private static ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public InsertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> inputArray){
    InsertionSort.array = array;
}
```

Why creating an instance in this case ?

`InsertionSort` has a state that is specific to the `List` that you pass to, so you should not use `static` modifiers for members of it that should be associated to **one** instance of `InsertionSort`.
So replace the static modifiers by instance modifiers.

Comment: Also, why use a static value for array?

Comment: That being said, I think it is good to focus on the problem at hand, then causally mention the other things that might want to be fixed. It is that time of year when people start those CS-101 classes, eh?

Comment: Probably.  That's why I added a horizontal line. Such incorrect use of static/instance is rather "embarassing" but for beginner this is almost normal ;)

Comment: Hey davidxxx, thank you so much! Really appreciate that! I dont really know.. I kept getting errors and I wanted to get rid of them, so I tried a whole lot. Anyway, I changed it to your suggestion (i don't really get the static modifiers part completely though). It is running now, but the array is not being sorted correctly. This class I am following is killing me, but I gotta get this right..

Comment: you are welcome. You have a little mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can change the program so the teacher can just type in an array and get the sorted output, instead of having to change the code by adding to the list?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do things statically, but you don't have it quite right.  Look at davidxxx's solution if you want to do it that way.  If you don't want to do it statically.  If you don't want to do things statically...

In your for loops, you are trying to call your InsertionSort methods statically.  You need to use the InsertionSort object you already created (sort).

Your for loops should look like this...

```
for(int i:sort.inputArray())
```

Also, your InsertionSort constructor isn't right.  It should look like...

```
public InsertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> inputArray){
        InsertionSort.array = inputArray;
}
```

There is also one small problem in your sorting method.  In your inner loop, you are correctly setting the value of index i+1 to the value at index i.  However, you are then setting index i+1 equal to the "key" value, which ensures that your array will never change.  Here is the correct algorithm.

```
public void doInsertionSort(){
    for (int j = 1; j<array.size(); j++){
        int key = array.get(j);
        for (int i=j-1; i>=0 && array.get(i)> key; i--){ //I moved i's declaration here for simplicity.
            array.set(i+1,array.get(i));
            array.set(i, key); //This is the line that I changed!
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't actually tried compiling/running this yet, so let me know if this works or not.

Comment: @Tam, there is also a problem in your sorting method/algorithm.  I am updating my answer with a correction.

Comment: Got it!!

public void doInsertionSort(){
  for (int j = 1; j<array.size(); j++){
   int key = array.get(j);
   int i= j-1 ;
   while(i>=0 && array.get(i)>key){
    array.set(i+1,array.get(i));
    i--;
    array.set(i+1, key);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: @Tam, I would recommend you use my solution instead of what you just posted.  Using a for loop makes it much easier to see what is going on, and it is generally best to only increment i at the beginning or end of your loop (not in the middle).

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can change the program so the teacher can just type in an array and get the sorted output, instead of having to change the code by adding to the list?

Comment: @Tam Yeah, I do.  It is relatively simple.  Rather than explain it here, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795350/how-to-put-a-scanner-input-into-an-array-for-example-a-couple-of-numbers) is almost identical to what you are trying to do, so you can look there for information.  Let me know if you need anything else!  By the way, I would appreciate it if you could upvote/accept my answer if it was helpful to you.  :)