# Passing an uncertain amount of Int's through an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am in an intro Java Programming class and I am trying to figure out how to populate an array from user inputted Int's. I've watched all my professor's videos and done a bunch of google searches, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesForClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello Drews, how many total grades do you want to process?");
        int numberOfGrades = keyboard.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter grade " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            int userGradeNumbers = keyboard.nextInt();
            sum += userGradeNumbers;            
        }

        int storeGrades[] = new int[userGradeNumbers];

        int totalScore = sum;
        //int lowestScore = ;
        //int highestScore = ;
        double averageScore = sum / (double) numberOfGrades;

        System.out.println("Total score is: " + totalScore);
        //System.out.println("Lowest score is: " + lowestScore);
        //System.out.println("Highest score is: " + highestScore);
        System.out.println("Average score is: " + averageScore);

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a Scanner input into an array... for example a couple of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795350/how-to-put-a-scanner-input-into-an-array-for-example-a-couple-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this (which creates a `storeGrades` array with no grades):

```
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter grade " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        int userGradeNumbers = keyboard.nextInt();
        sum += userGradeNumbers;            
    } 

    int storeGrades[] = new int[userGradeNumbers];
```

do this:

```
    int storeGrades[] = new int[numberOfGrades];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter grade " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        int grade = keyboard.nextInt();
        storeGrades[i] = grade;
        sum += grade;            
    }
```

After the above for-loop, `storeGrades` will contain the individual grades.

Comment: thank you very much. this made a lot of sense. the part i was missing was that stinkin [i].

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how many grades you'll be processing, the simplest thing would be to create an array *before* you start asking for input from the user.

```
int[] storeGrades = new int[numberOfGrades];
```

instead of *after* the user input, which is where you currently have it.

Once you have that, you can reference the elements of the array using a number from 0 to `numberOfGrades - 1`.  In particular, *inside* the loop where you input the numbers, you could have

```
storeGrades[i] = userGradeNumbers;
```

since `i` is an index that traverses precisely the range you require.

Comment: i actually dont know how many ill be processing which is why i have the for loop.

also im getting an error at the sttoreGrades[i] = userGradeNumbers;

Comment: you do know how many you are processing because you have the user input it in numberOfGrades at the top of your code.

Comment: As soon as you've done `int numberOfGrades = keyboard.nextInt();`, then you know how many grades there will be - the user has just told you.  So make sure the initialisation of `storeGrades` comes _after_ that line, and you'll be fine.

Comment: huh. i guess im just not understanding the definition of known. What I mean is that in all the examples my professor gives me, it shows how to setup an array with x amount of numbers (like this: {45, 63, 1, 20}). What his examples dont show are when you dont have those specific  numbers and you have to ask the users and then assign them to the integers collected.

I guess where I am wrong is that I am trying to collect those numbers from integers and not from [i] the indeces?