# How do I read in values for the elements of an array from a Scanner passed in?

Tags: java

For this simple program we were given 2 classes to work with `MyDate` and `DueDates` (and of course `main` class). After initializing the Array of objects of `MyDate` class `private MyDate [] dueDates = new MyDate[10]`, a specific function asks us to 'read in values for the dates in the array from the scanner passed in'.

I was very confused by that, because I -as a weak programmer- have only used `Scanner` for stuff like `System.in` and the like. Which wasn't what I didn't understand; it was 'How' can I read in those values? Since I wasn't able to use `input.next()` or what not as it is an array of type Class.

```java
public class DueDates {
    private MyDate[] dueDates ;

    public DueDates() {
        //*****  write the code for this method here
        dueDates = new MyDate [10];
    }

    //set array to have size of parameter passed in
    public DueDates(int max) {
        //*****  write the code for this method here
        dueDates = new MyDate[max];
    }

    /*reads in values for the dates in the array from the Scanner passed in ------having issues here*/
    public boolean inputDueDates(Scanner in) {
        //*****  write the code for this method here
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        dueDates = in.  // I'm lost at this point
        return true;
    }
}
```

````java
public class MyDate {
        private int day = 1;
        private int month = 1;
        private int year = 2018;

        public MyDate() {
        }

        public String toString() {   
            return new String ("" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day);
        }

        public boolean inputDate(Scanner in) {
            month = 0;
            day = 0; 
            year = 0;
            do {

                System.out.print ("Enter month - between 1 and 12: ");
                if (in.hasNextInt())
                    this.month = in.nextInt();
                else {
                    System.out.println ("Invalid month input");
                    in.next();
                }
            } while (this.month <= 0 || this.month > 12);

            do {

                System.out.print ("Enter day - between 1 and 31: ");
                if (in.hasNextInt())
                    this.day = in.nextInt();
                else {
                    System.out.println ("Invalid day input");
                    in.next();
                }
            } while (this.day <= 0 || this.day > 31 || (this.month == 2 && this.day > 29) || (this.day > 30 && (this.month == 9 ||this.month == 4 ||this.month == 6 ||this.month == 11) ) );

            do {
                System.out.print ("Enter year: ");
                if (in.hasNextInt())
                    this.year = in.nextInt();
                else {
                    System.out.println ("Invalid day input");
                    in.next();
                }
            } while (this.year <= 0);

            return true;        
        }```
^^^^is what was given to us, im not sure if the prof forgot to complete the constructor or simply it needs to be empty as is, but hope this clears it up more.

I can provide the other class if need be, and/or the sample output, but I'm genuinely just stuck at this point, sorry and thanks.
````

Comment: Very similar question [How to put a Scanner input into an array… for example a couple of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795350/how-to-put-a-scanner-input-into-an-array-for-example-a-couple-of-numbers)

Comment: Use a loop. At each iteration, read what needs to be read from the scanner, create a MyDate object using what you just read, and store it in the array. There's no magic method taht will fill your array all at once. You need to write code.

Comment: Better you elaborate about the MyDate class and yes you need loop iteration for Arrays.

Comment: @Yugansh I edited the post with the MyDate Class, seems what she provided was an empty constructor, and didn't tell us to edit it, so im not sure what then :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'read in values for the dates in the array from the scanner passed in' simply means to pass in an already instantiated scanner object into a method and use it to read in user input.

The method signature may look like this:

```java
public boolean doTheThing(Scanner sc){
    //Use a loop to read in user input with sc
    //return true/false 
}
```

The "passed in" part refers to the `Scanner sc` parameter of the method signature.

Let's take a look at the javadocs for scanner:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Of particular interest are:

1. `hasNextInt()`
2. `nextInt()`

With `hasNextInt()` you can check your input stream scanner has an int. Then you can use `nextInt()` to grab it. This only works for getting one such int, so you'll need to encase it into a loop.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried editing the line "dueDates = in.hasNextInt();" to this, but its giving me the same issue of, type mismatch ' cannot convert dueDates from boolean to MyDate[]... sorry im confused about what exactly needs to be fixed there. Also check out my edit including the MyDate class :/

Comment: `hasNextInt()`, according to the javadocs, return type is `boolean` whereas your `dueDate` array is of type `MyDate`.  That's where the type mismatch is comming from. The `hasNextInt()` mehod should be used to check to see if there are any ints to grab ___before___ you grab it. ___If___ there are any ints to grab, then use `nextInt` to grab it. Note: the return type of `nextInt()` is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the MyDate constructor is:
  `Date(int day, int month, int year){...}`

Now you need to initialize 10 dates, so you can use a for-loop:

```
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        int day = in.nextInt();
        int month = in.nextInt();
        int year = in.nextInt();

        dueDates[i]=new MyDate(day, month, year);
      }
```

Comment: The default constructor based on what she gave was empty as show in my edit above. Tho im clear on how to loop it, I just wasn't able to due to it being of type MyClass. But I think thats probably cuz the constructor is empty :/